# When would "tenthly" occur in this context?

Tags: meaning

Say you have several options for how often you get paid:

- Weekly
- Biweekly
- Monthly
- Tenthly
- Annually

When would "tenthly" occur?

Comment: Where have you heard *tenthly* used in this sense? Also be aware that *biweekly*, for instance, has two senses that contradict each other: twice a week and every two weeks. Using *biweekly* is currently discouraged because of its ambiguous meaning. (Even though it is still used anyway.)

Comment: I don't believe "tenthly" describes a pattern of payment. The only thing I can see it being used for is if you're listing points and numbering them off, you would say "firstly," "secondly,"..."tenthly," etc.

Comment: I would replace "biweekly" with "fortnightly" but the time period "fortnight" seems to be dropping out of use.

Comment: Six months, half-yearly, every ten months, every ten weeks.

Comment: @JasonBassford I modified the scenario I saw it in, which was educational material about saving for retirement. You can contribute to your 401k Weekly, Biweekly, Monthly, Tenthly, or Annually.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that *tenthly* was a real word.  I suspect that given that it's uncommon in any context, its meaning here would have to be defined by the person using it.  That is, it could mean on the tenth of the month, the tenth month (illegal in the US generally speaking, I believe), or perhaps every tenth day.

So without defining exactly what is meant, there is no way to determine its place in your list.

As a side note, I see *by its placement in your list* that you most likely mean *every two weeks* when you write *[biweekly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/biweekly)*, rather than its alternate meaning of *twice a week*.  Similarly, based on your placement of *tenthly* and absent any other information, I would assume it means *every ten months*.

Comment: *Tenthly* is as much a word as *firstly* is. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenthly

Comment: Or, considering **paid firstly** if you are **paid tenthly** you will be the 10th person to be paid.

Comment: @NathanM. -- I realize it is a word; I just hadn't ever heard or seen it and it never would have occurred to me that it was.

Comment: @WeatherVane -- I suppose that works, but I think I would be more likely to say **paid first** or **paid tenth** (whether or not that's correct.)

Comment: I don’t think that it should be used, just as *firstly* and *secondly* shouldn’t be. Especially not when *first* and *second* and *tenth* are much more prevalent than their -ly counterparts. https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/first-or-firstly

Comment: If you're paid every ten days, i.e., 3 times a month, I would recommend you say just that: "I'm paid every ten days."  This is an unusual interval, though: most people are paid daily, or weekly, or every two weeks (or twice a month), or monthly.